# Unity Input System - The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine'

Tags: unity

I've just installed the Input System Package in Unity. Visual Studio Code is not recognizing the InputSystem namespace on the line `using UnityEngine.InputSystem;`, reporting that:

`The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine'.`

Unity compiles the script just fine and it works correctly, so the issue is something with the Unity/Visual Studio interaction. I'm using Unity 2021.2.8f1 and Visual Studio Code 2021 1.63.2.

I've tried everything suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636944/unity-type-or-namespace-name-inputsystem-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-unit), including:

- Installed the Input System in Unity by going to Package Manager -> Input System -> Install.
- After installing, clicked 'yes' on the popup to use the new system instead of the legacy system. I confirmed this by going to Project Settings -> Player -> Configuration -> Active Input Handling and confirming that Input System Package (New) is selected.
- Regenerated project files by going to Preferences -> External Tools -> checking all boxes and clicking Regenerate project files. I also made sure that the External Script Editor is chosen as Visual Studio Code.
- Confirmed that the Visual Studio Code Editor package is installed in Unity.
- Deleted the project's Library folder.
- Deleted the project's .csproj files in the project's root directory.
- Restarted Unity and Visual Studio Code.
- Restarted my computer.

Comment: Are there any spaces in the path to Unity? I had a problem where VSCode didn't recognize symbols because of spaces in the path.

Comment: Do you mean the location that Unity is installed at? I have it as `C:\Program Files\Unity`.

Comment: Yeah, precisely that.

Comment: Have you tried clearing/rebuilding the cache? For VS Code I think it's: `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` and then under `Index workspace`.